# Взаимодействие двух ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

В первом я создаю блок. Второй должен его удалять. Однако почему-то не удаляет, хотя в других случаях всё работает. Т.е. когда я делаю append с загрузкой страницы через php, то всё ок. А если добавляю с помощью ajax, то к нему уже не применяется удаление. Как можно исправить?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#sub').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
                url: "../register/writes/wall_support.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "text",
                data: {write: $('#textarea').val(), button: $('#sub').val()},
                success: function(data) {
                    var arr = data.split('^');
                    var app = '<div value="'+arr[3]+'" class="read"><img src="../img/support.png" align="left"> <div class="united"><span style="color: #3333FF;">Поддержка <button class="deletewrite" value="'+arr[3]+'" title="Удалить"></button></span><br/><div style="width: 95%;">'+arr[0]+'</div><span style="color: #515151; font-size: 0.8em; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">Опубликовал '+arr[1]+' администратор '+arr[2]+'</span></div></div>';
                    $(app).insertAfter("#after");
                    $('#textarea').val('');
                    $('#allwrites').text('Всего '+arr[4]+' записей');
                }
        })
});

$('.deletewrite').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                url: "../register/writes/wall_support.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "text",
                data: {number: value},
                success: function(data) {
                    $(this).parents('.read').remove();
                    $('#allwrites').text('Всего'+data+' записей');
                }
        })
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы подгружаете элемент с классом `deletewrite` через аякс но забываете привязать к нем уобработчик события, поэтому ничего и не происходит воспользуйтесь `live` или `delegate`, например:

```
$('.deletewrite').live('click',function() {
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Всё работает!

Comment: Так как с версии jQuery 1.7, .live() метод устаревший.

    $(".deletewrite").on("click", function(){ ... });

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, кэпшн вопроса никак не соответствует тому, что вам требуется...Возможно, вы допустили ошибку здесь:

```
    dataType: "text",
```

Вы указываете PHP-скрипту, что ожидаете от него обыкновенный текст, а не HTML-код. Вот он вам и "отвечает" обычным текстом, который никак не может быть обработанным браузером, как HTML и/или JS! Замените эту ошибку на это:

```
    dataType: "html",
```

**Должно помочь...**

---

Еще неплохо было бы добавить в формируемый jQuery Ajax запрос функцию "error", на равне с "success". Это поможет в устранинеии ошибок, если алертить в этой функции текстовое сообщение ошибки.

Comment: Нет не в этом дело.